# how to fix utils pylint import error on virtual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

As seen in the picture, I keep getting this error. I installed and checked pylint but I can't seem to figure out what seems to be the problem. How to fix this problem in virtual studio code? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Pylint has [known issues recognizing tensorflow submodules](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2603). You can either disable the warning for those specific lines, disable import warnings globally, or disable Pylint.